# Ignore files within a subdirectory using gitignore

Tags: git, bash, github, gitignore, git-bash

I'm trying to create a gitignore file for git that ignores any .file within any dir/. I want to ignore all instances of .file inside instances of a dir/. These are specific file formats and directory.

For example, .file is the file format of new.file. The dir/ is the directory that houses new.file. The path is `dir/new.file`.

I need git to ignore possible instances of .file within possible instances of dir/, which may appear arbitrarily.

I tested these:

```
**/dir/*.file
*/dir/*.file
*/dir/**/*.file
dir/**/*.file
```

However, whenever I create a `foo/dir/new[*].file`, I was able to `git add` it and also `git commit` the file.

All new instances of the file format .file within a dir/ directory are added to staging with `git add .` or `git add -A`. I expect `git` to ignore these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`**/dir/**/*.file` seems to work as you specify, at least in my tests. Is is possible that you already have the files in question in the repo and have to remove them first?

```
git rm --cached <filepath>
```

Comment: I assume gitignore prevents `git` from adding the file to staging. I'll try to clarify my question.

Comment: I see now.  I am finding that `**/dir/**/*.file` seems to work  for me as you specify.  Is is possible that you already have the files in question in the repo and have to remove them first?
`git rm --cached <filepath>` might help with that.

Comment: This works. I've tested this on various levels. First, `foo/dir/new.file` does not stage. Second, `Two/Three/Four/dir/new.file` does not stage. Third, `Two/Three/Four/dir/Five/new.file` does not stage.